# sqlite пронумеровать строки в порядке возрастания, после применения фильтра

Tags: sql, sqlite

имеется таблица:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

в ней около 100 записей, которые все время пополняются. Мне нужно составить запрос, который будет на основе userID (который может в разных строках повторяться при разном guildID) суммировать всю репутацию пользователя (reputation), возвращая ответ в виде двух столбов userID и totalRep. Сам запрос я составил подобным образом:

```
    WITH SortedRows AS (SELECT SUM(reputation) AS totalRep, userID FROM UserPermissionData GROUP BY userID) SELECT * FROM SortedRows ORDER BY totalRep DESC
```

соответственно мне возвращается:
[image: Ответ после запроса]

подскажите, как мне получить номер строки пользователя с определенным userID? Каким образом мне стоит дополнить запрос или же полностью его поменять? Я не мастер в sql запросах, как можно было понять по выше написанному, *rowid* в данном случае не доступен, так как SortedRows временная таблица из которого нельзя извлечь номер строки. Могу ли я что то поменять, что бы его получить? Спасибо за любой ответ или подсказку.

Comment: ROW_NUMBER https://www.sqlite.org/windowfunctions.html

Comment: @ГерманБорисов, благодарю за ответ, я много времени потратил на поиски и не мог нормально сформулировать вопрос, что б меня понял поисковик, в конце концов решившись написать вопрос, ещё раз я очень вам благодарен, это помогло.